# How to load files into ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm trying to build a function in Haskell. I created a plain text file with the following function:

```
doubleme x = x + x
```

I saved it under baby.txt.

I navigated to the file from the command line, then I did the following from the command line:

```
ghci
Prelude> :l baby
```

it returned:

```
target ‘baby’ is not a module name or a source file
```

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong and how to make the function compile?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard sorry I'm new to Haskell and using the command line and I can't find a good explanation online. Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Haskell files use `.hs` extensions, not `.txt` extensions. I strongly recommend reading [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) before diving into SO questions. This is minimum effort research.

Comment: You should name your module files as in `Module.hs` (e.g. `Baby.hs`) with the `hs` extension and uppercase initial.

Comment: @AJFarmar The OP is presumably reading LYAH, as this example [comes from there](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#babys-first-functions). That said, LYAH does suggest readers to save the file as `baby.hs` (that is, with the appropriate `hs` extension).

Answer (score 12):

You should name the file with .hs extension.  and loading it using command  :l in ghci

```
Prelude> :l baby.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( baby.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main>
*Main>
*Main>
*Main> :t doubleme
doubleme :: Num a => a -> a
```